# Windows batch file to minimize all open windows

Tags: windows, batch

I would like to have a batch file in Windows where when it is executed it minimizes all the open windows on the desktop?

Essentially, I would like this batch file to clear the screen clutter so when I launch an app it is the 'only window' on the desktop.

Although I've seen 'Show Desktop.scf' in several posts, I can't seem to incorporate that into a batch file so it runs - I must be missing something so any assistance would be much appreciated.

I have a mixed Win7 and Win10 environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just in case you were unaware... if you drag the window you want to keep and shake it left and right a few times, windows will automatically minimize all but that window. Shake it again to undo. Also to launch the Show desktop.scf file from a batchfile, use `start "Show Desktop.scf"`. And lastly, WIN+D or WIN+M will minimize all windows too. A .vbscript can be created that does a `set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")` `objShell.MinimizeAll` too. :)

Comment: "if you drag the window you want to keep and shake it left and right a few times, windows will automatically minimize all but that window" TIL... wow, that's absolutely wild. Only works on my primary display in my setup, but still amazing.

Comment: Please show how you have tried using the start "show desktop.scf" command in scripts. Use the EDIT button to add this information to the body of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method would be to not use a .cmd or .bat file, but create a .vbs file instead.

Writing that script for this task is fairly simple and can be run as well by a simple double-click too.

But a .vbs can do much more in case you want to actually go that route in the future.

Here's an example script that minimizes all windows, then runs a Command Prompt.

```
set oShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

oShellApp.MinimizeAll
oShellApp.ShellExecute "cmd.exe"
```

*See also: [VBScript Shell.Application](https://ss64.com/vb/shell.html)*

Comment: I'll go with the VB script option - thanks LPChip and those who offered support.